# find out the file system from a tape

Tags: tape, lto

Is there any way to find out the file system from a tape under Linux (**CentOS**)? I need this to figure out if a tape is already **LTFS** or not.

At the moment I know:

- mtx `# for managing a tape library`
- mt `# for controlling the tape`
- tapeinfo `# for general tape information`
- tapestat `# for statistics`
- mkltfs `# for formatting a tape`
- ltfs `# for mounting a tape`
- unltfs `# for removing the file system from tape`

I think none of them can show the actual file system from a tape.

Have you any suggestion for me?

Comment: A tape can contain arbitrary data. It does not have to be a filesystem at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mostly a wild guess, but ...

The first thing I would probably try is a raw read of the first ~1MB of the tape to a tempfile.   Then try using `file tempfile`.  The `file` command can recognize many types data types based on what it finds.

Comment: Thank you! I have now try this: ``dd if=/dev/st1 of=st1-raw bs=256 count=2000000000000``, but I can also do it with count=2000, both time I get a 80b file. The command **file ...** gives me: ``st1-raw: ASCII text, with no line terminators`` but when I open the file with less the content is this: ``VOL1      L             LTFS                                                   4``. I'm not exactly understand why I get no bigger file, and when I do the same command with an empty tape, my dd output has 0b, but in a way I get the information, I need.

Comment: This appears to be the first partition of the tape and pretty obviously it's LTFS. Have you tried mouting it?

Comment: Yes I can mount the tape, I only needed a way to figure out before mounting, that there is LTFS on it or not.